# Can we fetch a single row data from csv file in ADLS using Azure data factory

Tags: azure, azure-sql-database, azure-storage, azure-data-factory

I need to pick a time stamp data from a column ‘created on’ from a csv file in ADLS. Later I want to query Azure SQL DB like delete from table where created on = ‘time stamp’ in ADF. Please help on how could this be achieved.

Comment: can you please add mode details about what you have tried and error you are facing?

Comment: I have a data flow that would map the source csv files into a final required output csv. This final output csv is inserted finally into Azure SQL using copy activity. So my question was is it possible to fetch a value from the csv in storage and then use that value to query the DB. Like fetch the ‘time stamp’ data from csv and query the DB using the fetched value something like delete from table where created on = ‘time stamp’. I just need to know if we can fetch a data from csv in storage using ADF .

Answer (score 0):

Here I repro'd to fetch a selected row from the CSV in ADLS.

Create a Linked service and Dataset of the source file.
[image]

[image]

Read the Data by the Lookup Activity from the Source path.
[image]
For each activity iterates the values from the output of `Lookup.@activity('Lookup1').output.value`
[image]

Inside of `For Each` activity use `Append Variable` and `set Variable` Use value for append variable from the For each item records.
[image]
Using it as Index variable.
[image]
[image]

Use script activity to run query and reflect the script on the data.
[image]

```
Delete FROM dbo.test_table where Created_on = @{variables('Date_COL3')[4]}
```

[image]
[image]